# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById returns null for google maps in fragment in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment

I have a problem with Google Maps, i.e. getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById returns always null. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Here is the code:

```
fragment_map.xml:

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myapp.something.MapFragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />                  
</FrameLayout>
```

MapsFragment.java:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, android.location.LocationListener

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
...
```

I have Google Maps in Activity and it works with code:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

I am trying to reuse this in fragment, becouse I need maps in fragment, not in activity, but it doesn't work.

I tried:

- calling this code in "onCreateView" function
- `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`
- `GoogleMap mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` is deprecated, and application crashes
- `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`
  and similar variations, but in all cases I get null for mapFragment.

Do you know how could I solve this problem?

Comment: You got to use `onCreateView` for Fragments. Could you post the log here so that we can know what the error is?

Comment: If I use `onCreateView` I still get this error. You can see error report in my question update

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the Activity's FragmentManager, and you should be using the Fragment's child FragmentManager.

Remove the `onCreate()` override in the Fragment, and add an `onCreateView()` Override where you inflate the layout and call `getMapAsync()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Tnx for the reply, but this code also dosen't work. `findFragmentById` still returns null.

Comment: Done. Tnx again :)

Comment: @Aboulfotoh  Your specific issue is probably different than the OP's issue here.  How exactly does it not work for you?

Comment: @DanielNugent it give me a null reference object

Comment: @Aboulfotoh Does your layout xml look like `fragment_map.xml` in the question?

Comment: @DanielNugent Yes, exactly the same

Comment: @Aboulfotoh What exactly is null for you?

Comment: @DanielNugent it worked fine now, I was using ButterKnife and it cuases the problem

Comment: I had the same problem. It took me a lot of time before seeing you answer. Thanks to you it worked. Thanks.

Comment: But why? Why I should use getChildFragmentManager()?

Comment: @deadfish It's just how they set up the framework.  If you use a SupportMapFragment inside an activity, you can just use the activity fragment manager.  If you use a SupportMapFragment inside of a fragment, you then have nested fragments, and you need to use the outer fragment's child fragment manager in order for it to work.